# MS SQL CASE WHEN Snippet looks ok to me, but is returning an 'expression of non-boolean type' error

Tags: sql-server

I need to modify an existing SQL view. But the new code, this particular snippet, is causing an error:

```
(CASE WHEN NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe
```

The error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

As far as I can see, I have provided a boolean answer (=0). The view returns data fine without the above snippet. I also tried placing the (NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0) in parentheses.

The full view can be seen here if interested:

What am I not getting?

Thanks

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VwCenNLAcccountPeriodMatrix]
AS
SELECT        dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountName, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountNumber, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre, CASE WHEN P1Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P1Values.ActualVal END AS P1Act, CASE WHEN P1Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P1Values.BudgetVal END AS P1Budget, CASE WHEN P2Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P2Values.ActualVal END AS P2Act, CASE WHEN P2Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P2Values.BudgetVal END AS P2Budget, CASE WHEN P3Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P3Values.ActualVal END AS P3Act, CASE WHEN P3Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P3Values.BudgetVal END AS P3Budget, CASE WHEN P4Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P4Values.ActualVal END AS P4Act, CASE WHEN P4Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P4Values.BudgetVal END AS P4Budget, CASE WHEN P5Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P5Values.ActualVal END AS P5Act, CASE WHEN P5Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P5Values.BudgetVal END AS P5Budget, CASE WHEN P6Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P6Values.ActualVal END AS P6Act, CASE WHEN P6Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P6Values.BudgetVal END AS P6Budget, CASE WHEN P7Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P7Values.ActualVal END AS P7Act, CASE WHEN P7Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P7Values.BudgetVal END AS P7Budget, CASE WHEN P8Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P8Values.ActualVal END AS P8Act, CASE WHEN P8Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P8Values.BudgetVal END AS P8Budget, CASE WHEN P9Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P9Values.ActualVal END AS P9Act, CASE WHEN P9Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P9Values.BudgetVal END AS P9Budget, CASE WHEN P10Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P10Values.ActualVal END AS P10Act, CASE WHEN P10Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P10Values.BudgetVal END AS P10Budget, CASE WHEN P11Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P11Values.ActualVal END AS P11Act, CASE WHEN P11Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P11Values.BudgetVal END AS P11Budget, CASE WHEN P12Values.ActualVal IS NULL 
                         THEN 0 ELSE P12Values.ActualVal END AS P12Act, CASE WHEN P12Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P12Values.BudgetVal END AS P12Budget, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment, 
                         dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.Code AS RepCatCode, dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.Description AS RepCatDesc, dbo.NLAccountReportType.Name AS RepType, 
                         dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment + '/' + dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.Code AS DepCode, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre + '/' + dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.Code AS CCCode, 
                         CASE WHEN ((CASE WHEN P1Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P1Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P1Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P1Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P2Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P2Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P2Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P2Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P3Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P3Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P3Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P3Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P4Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P4Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P4Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P4Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P5Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P5Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P5Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P5Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P6Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P6Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P6Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P6Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P7Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P7Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P7Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P7Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P8Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P8Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P8Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P8Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P9Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P9Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P9Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P9Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P10Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P10Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P10Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P10Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P11Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P11Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P11Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P11Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND 
                         (CASE WHEN P12Values.ActualVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P12Values.ActualVal END) = 0 AND (CASE WHEN P12Values.BudgetVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE P12Values.BudgetVal END) = 0 AND
                        (CASE WHEN NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe, dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre + '/' + dbo.NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment + '/' + dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.Code AS CCDepCode
FROM            dbo.NLAccountReportCategory INNER JOIN
                         dbo.NLNominalAccount ON dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.NLAccountReportCategoryID = dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLAccountReportCategoryID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.NLAccountReportType ON dbo.NLAccountReportCategory.NLAccountReportTypeID = dbo.NLAccountReportType.NLAccountReportTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_2
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 2)) AS P2Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P2Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_1
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 1)) AS P1Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P1Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_3
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 3)) AS P3Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P3Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_4
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 4)) AS P4Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P4Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_5
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 5)) AS P5Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P5Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_6
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 6)) AS P6Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P6Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_7
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 7)) AS P7Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P7Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_8
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 8)) AS P8Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P8Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_9
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 9)) AS P9Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P9Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_10
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 10)) AS P10Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P10Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_11
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 11)) AS P11Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P11Values.NLNominalAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        NLNominalAccountID, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), ActualValue) + CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), AdjustmentAfterYearEndClose) AS ActualVal, PeriodNumber, CONVERT(decimal(18, 5), BudgetValue) 
                                                         AS BudgetVal
                               FROM            dbo.VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue AS VwCenNLAccountPeriodValue_12
                               WHERE        (PeriodNumber = 12)) AS P12Values ON dbo.NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID = P12Values.NLNominalAccountID

GO
```

Comment: You haven't finished the whole big enchilada of case when expressions. Your inner part is fine, but you have an outer part which dangles in the air. I would suggest to rewrite the whole thing because it's impossible to understand, but i have a feeling it's a waste of a comment

Comment: That's a stack of CASE statements that are just trying to deal with NULL values.  I'd suggest using ISNULL() or COALESCE() instead

Comment: This view is a complete horror show and should be totally rewritten. Here is a start https://dbfiddle.uk/9A_L28Cg

Comment: Before you go further, at a minimum learn about the following: `ISNULL` function, conditional aggregation using `SUM(CASE`, the `APPLY` operator, table aliases, good formatting. Otherwise you are going to sink further and further into a hole.

Comment: The reason you got that error is that you are already in a `CASE` and you then do `AND (CASE WHEN NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe` which should instead be simply `AND NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe`

Comment: Your nested case is incomplete, `CASE WHEN (... AS IncludeMe`. As already mentioned, pretty much all of these individual case expressions can be replaced with a much simpler, cleaner and easier to read `ISNULL(..., 0)`.

Comment: I totally get that this is a shitshow, I've inherited a lot of excrement I'm discovering. Completely agree a rewrite is in order. Thanks for your help, I looked at this so long it made less and less sense. Sorted for now thank you!

Comment: I hope you will expand and use **@Charlieface's excellent fiddle rewrite**. Nice work!. A couple of follow-up notes: You will need to add something like `COUNT(NULLIF(pv.ActualValue,0)) AS CountOfActuals` to the cross apply, so that you can reference it in the `IncludeMe` conditions above. The same is needed for Budget. The `NULLIF()` acts like the opposite of `ISNULL()`, and allows you to only count non-zero values. Lastly, don't forget the adjustment when you get to the `P12Act` calculation.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific line you highlighted, you're just writing the case statement, you're not actually specifying what the outcome of the case statement needs to be.

To answer it more specifically, you need to add your 'THEN' statement in at the end of that final case

Answer (score 0):

I totally get that this is a shitshow, I've inherited a lot of excrement I'm discovering. Completely agree a rewrite is in order. Thanks for your help, I looked at this so long it made less and less sense. Sorted for now thank you!

This view is a complete horror show and should be totally rewritten. Here is a start dbfiddle.uk/9A_L28Cg –
Charlieface

The reason you got that error is that you are already in a CASE and you then do AND (CASE WHEN NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe which should instead be simply AND NLNominalAccount.DebitYearToDate - NLNominalAccount.CreditYearToDate = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IncludeMe –
Charlieface